# Grouping overlapping items in d3js map style

Tags: d3.js

I'm creating an event timeline graph to visualize events on a time line. The data structure looks roughly like

```
interface GraphData {
  from: Date;
  until: Date;
  groups: GraphGroup[];
}

interface GraphGroup{
  events: GraphEvent[];
}

interface Event {
  time: Date;
}
```

That's just the important parts, an event can also have a category, severity etc, example with random data:

[image: example graph]

Is there any way to group the data when overlapping in a map (like leaflet) style?

Example:

[image: example grouping in a map]

Ideas I had, but which aren't exactly what I'm looking for:

- use non d3js [elementsFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint) - but that only delivers all elements under the mouse cursor and not "overlapping elements in that area"
- use a [collideForce](https://observablehq.com/@d3/collision-detection/2), but that would make the position of the data points wrong (also I can't get it working, I guess I'm doing something wrong in relates to the nested data arrays. So before investing more time into that idea I'd like to hear if the community has a better approach)

So is there anything D3js offers to solve such a problem or would I have to come up with something completely custom?

Comment: If you want to emulate Leaflet's cluster behavior on a map built with D3, you could use [Supercluster](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster). Your pictures seem to indicate that your application is one dimensional, though. Thus, there might be an easier way.

Comment: A collide force can be used to keep positions if points share the same coordinates.   You can also optimize by just using d3-quadtree ([eg](https://jsfiddle.net/qrenumbv/): the lines represent clustering of different points at each zoom level - the lines indicate what points are pulled into each cluster). If your clustering points that aren't identical you'll be moving them anyways with or without d3-force. As centroids drift, d3-force or my example (and possibly other solutions) will cause centroids to drift as each point is clustered one at a time, possibly resulting in some mismatches.